# inAppBilling Module for android subscription not getting all required parameters

Tags: google-play-services, appcelerator, in-app-billing, subscription

I'm using the titanium module inAppBilling 3.0.1 For Android subscriptions, but I'm not getting the parameter called "autoRenewing".

Answer (score 0):

Subscription is auto renewing by default. Subscriptions can be cancelled from the My Apps screen in the Play Store app.Billing continues indefinitely at the interval and price specified for the subscription.
So I don't think there is any need for this parameter. Also inAppBilling 3.0.2 is out there with latest features and bug fixes. It is recommended to use the latest module.